# How do I make animated drool?

Tags: fluid-simulation, procedural

How do I animate drool from nothing to a long string of drool with a rounded drop shape. To look exactly like what is on the tongue of this cat. I did this once with Shape keys but it was difficult to animate and adjust.

Is there a procedural approach?

[image]

Comment: I think it's important you describe why exactly was your approach bad - how was it difficult to animate and adjust? Did the head swing and you wanted to have some physics there? Was it static but maybe you still wanted some viscosity physics? Maybe you wanted a higher resolution instead of just a simple cylinder thickened at the end? 

Comment: Use a Fluid (Liquid Domain) with a relatively small Inflow Sphere (location: tip of tonge), high Viscosity Strength (https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.92/physics/fluid/type/domain/liquid/viscosity.html#bpy-types-fluiddomainsettings-viscosity-value) (try Strength=5), small Liquid FLIP Particle Radius, and can slow down the Time Scale (try=0.5 or less)

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady I remember exactly now the problem with using shape keys. It works if the source is fixed, if you move the source then it looks too rigid and unrealistic.

Answer (score 2):

Use a Fluid (Liquid Domain) with

- a relatively small Inflow Sphere (location: tip of tonge),
- high Viscosity Strength ([docs](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.92/physics/fluid/type/domain/liquid/viscosity.html#bpy-types-fluiddomainsettings-viscosity-value)) (try Strength=5),
- small Liquid FLIP Particle Radius
- and can slow down the Time Scale (try=0.5 or less)

"When it rains I always think of you: drip":  [image]

Note that I only simulate up to frame 50, and the lighting makes the single drip column look like there's a break when there isn't.

[image]

Comment: It doesn't do as I requested tho. But I did figure out that you can make the sphere bigger at the start and animate it smaller just a few frames after will give it that rounded tear shape. Thanks for the help.